# Android telephone directory

Tags: android

Is there any open source telephone directory application for Android or how can I make one myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the directory of the device.
With this class you can retrieve the contacts of the telephone :

```
public class Repository extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Repo);

        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);   

    }
}
```

Don't forget to add a permission in the Manifest :

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
```

I hope this will help you.
Michaël

Comment: Thanks! I tried the example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list . On emulator, is there some test database that I can use to test the code or do I have to built a new database to output names and phone numbers. I haven't used databases in Android before.

Comment: You just have to add new phone numbers in the contacts of the phone (emulator).