# How can I launch the 'Add Contact' activity in android

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how to launch the Add Contact' activity in android?
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list) post may help you out or at least point you in the right direction.

Hope this helps.

### Update 05/11/2015:

Per the comments, check out [vickey's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11663568/166712) for the appropriate solution.

Comment: No. I am looking for how can I launch Android's Add Contact Activiy programmically. I tried both this and remove the commented code, both do not work.
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.INSERT");
                   //intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/person");
                   startActivity(intent);

Comment: This answer is really old, here is the correct code as mentioned below: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, 
                               ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(intent);

Comment: doesn't look like an answer. You can't just answer with the links to other answers.

Answer (score 61):

API Level 5 and above solution

```
// Add listener so your activity gets called back upon completion of action,
// in this case with ability to get handle to newly added contact
myActivity.addActivityListener(someActivityListener);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

// Just two examples of information you can send to pre-fill out data for the
// user.  See android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents.Insert for the complete
// list.
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "some Contact Name");
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "some Phone Number");

// Send with it a unique request code, so when you get called back, you can
// check to make sure it is from the intent you launched (ideally should be
// some public static final so receiver can check against it)
int PICK_CONTACT = 100;
myActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Comment: This almost works for me but my onActivityResult method is not being called (the first line in this response was omitted because there is no method addActivityListener as far as I can tell)

Comment: how does one get back the name and number added from the returned intent in onActivityResult?

Comment: I prefere to use **ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT** instead of **ACTION_INSERT**

Comment: Just change ACTION_INSERT with ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT in the previous source code

Answer (score 46):

These two lines do the trick:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, 
                               ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: lol, I dont know why this is not the accepted answer. This is all you need really.

Answer (score 16):

This should be the snippet your are looking for:

```
Intent addContactIntent = new Intent(Contacts.Intents.Insert.ACTION, Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI);
addContactIntent.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Jean-Claude"); // an example, there is other data available
startActivity(addContactIntent)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have a phone no and want to save it in your own application then use this code it will move you to the "create contact" page of the default contact app.

```
  Intent addContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
  addContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
  addContactIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,phnno.getText().toString());
  startActivity(addContactIntent);
```

Answer (score 8):

I was also trying to do this. I was able to launch the activity using Android 2.2. I haven't tried using/testing this in other SDK versions though.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT, Uri.parse("tel:" + currentNum.getText())); //currentNum is my TextView, you can replace it with the number directly such as Uri.parse("tel:1293827")
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.EXTRA_FORCE_CREATE, true); //skips the dialog box that asks the user to confirm creation of contacts
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: I try this code but it`s did not skip confirm dialog box !

Answer (score 5):

If you need to add a phone number to an existing contact or create a new one (just as the native dialer does with a new phone number) this code might be just what you need:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
intent.putExtra(Insert.PHONE, digits);
intent.setType(People.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
startActivity(intent);
```

Just take a look at the Android's [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/d50636542410db761e2fa862e0a660d8cdd0085a/src/com/android/contacts/dialpad/DialpadFragment.java) for the `DialpadFragment` class, search for the method `getAddToContactIntent(String digits)`.

But as the [People](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.People.html) class is deprecated in api 10 you may want to use this line instead:

```
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent localintent = new Intent("android.intent.action.INSERT",ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
localintent.putExtra("phone", phoneNumber);
startActivity(localintent);
```