# how to add an existing contact to the "Phone contacts" Account

Tags: android, contacts, rawcontacts

iam adding a contact to the device using this code

```
long Contact_Id = 100;
ContentValues pCV =new ContentValues();
pCV.put(Contacts.People.NAME, "test");
pCV.put(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, Contact_Id);
Uri newContactUri = insertContentValues(cResolver,
                    Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI, pCV);
```

i want to add this contact to a certain Account. iam using this code below

```
ContentResolver cResolver = context.getContentResolver();
cResolver.insert(uri, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        getAccountType()); 

public ContentValues getAccountType() {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();  
    cv.put(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,  "com.sonyericsson.localcontacts");
    cv.put(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "Phone contacts");
    return cv;
}
```

this code actually is adding a new contact to the "Phone contacts" Account. but i want to add the contact that i added above ("test") to be added to the "Phone contacts".
how can i do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching I have found that the best way to insert a Contact to the Local Phone contacts is to assign the `ACCOUNT_TYPE`, `ACCOUNT_NAME` to `null` take a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10320903/1295292)

Comment: i don't agree, see my comment at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014832/getting-account-type-of-contacts-table-for-accessing-phone-contact/10320903#10320903)

Answer (score 1):

You can try both the solution as per your choice/requirement.Both are working perfectly

> To add contact open directly edit activity

```
    try {
        Intent addContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        addContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        addContactIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, number);
        addContactIntent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
        context.startActivity(addContactIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> option to create contact or add contact to existing contact

```
 try {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
        i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        //  i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "TESTTEST");
        i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, number);
        context.startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```