# Save country in Contact Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

There is a way to save the country name into a contact using Intent?
Im trying with this code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, contactName);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NOTES, description);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY, contactTown);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, contactCountry);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION, contactProvince);
```

But when i create a new contact, it comes without **CITY, COUNTRY AND REGION**

I appreciate any help!

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18972011/3983054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `POSTAL` intent field for this, it's a free-format text field:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, contactName);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NOTES, description);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, contactTown + ", " + contactCountry + " " + contactProvince);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL_ISPRIMARY, true);
```