# Add profile picture to contacts in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating a hybrid mobile app, using Xamarin.Forms.

I want the user to click a button and the contact in the app gets inserted into the phone's contacts, including the profile picture.

So far, everything on the iOS side is working. I successfully insert the profile picture.

I can't get it to work on Android though. I've already tried looking on here but all solutions use Java. Inserting the name, number and e-mail works perfectly.

Here is my code so far:

```
  public void SaveContacts(string name, string number, string email, string job, string company, byte[] imageData)
        {
            try
            {
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionInsert);
                intent.SetType(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentType);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                    intent.PutExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.Name, name);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number))
                    intent.PutExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.Phone, number);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
                    intent.PutExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.Email, email);


                if (imageData.Length != 0)
                {
                   // INSERT PROFILE PICTURE HERE
                }

                Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<ILogger>()?.Error(ex);
            }
        }
```

How do I add the profile picture to the contact?

Comment: *"all solutions use Java"*: The code above is in your Android project, so has access to Android APIs? Add to question a link to a java solution. Manually translate each line of java code into the corresponding xamarin.android call. Add the result to question. Indicate any lines that you are having trouble writing in c#.

Answer (score 0):

According to this case which is about [Insert Contact (ContactsContract) via Intent with Image (Photo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026292/insert-contact-contactscontract-via-intent-with-image-photo), you need to use the `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Insert.DATA, data)` method to add the photo to the new contact.

But I have create a sample to test it. This method have a bug. I use the following code:

```
List<ContentValues> data = new List<ContentValues>();
ContentValues row1 = new ContentValues();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionInsert);
intent.SetType(ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo);
intent.PutParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.Data, data);
```

But it will show the type convert error. Even though the class `ContentValues` is inherited from the `IParcelable` interface. The error still show. You can report it to the xamarin on the github.

In addition, I also try to use the method about [using the content provider to insert a contact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22343260/17455524). But the `RawContacts` doesn't have ACCOUNT_TYPE property.

So for the bug, it seems you can't add profile picture to contacts with the native api.