# How to add new contact in Phone in Android?

Tags: java, android, contacts

I know how can we add new contacts or edit existing contacts by using [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) or using [Contact](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html) , in these cases we have to design our own layout. But I saw default add contact layout of device is not same as other android device.

*So I want to use that default activity of android device, which is responsible for add new contacts. Is it possible to call that Activity? And which API label will be required.*

Minimum API level is 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895206/how-can-i-launch-the-add-contact-activity-in-android/3816521#3816521) answer, which API are you using?