# Show Dialog to add new contact from clicked phone number

Tags: java, android, dialog, contacts

My app has a page with textviews for displaying company phone numbers, and I was wondering how I can tell the android to pop up a dialog that wants to add the number as a contact when a user clicks it?  I have already defined the onclicklisteners so I don't need someone trying to explain that to me. I just need to know the proper approach to add the "Add as Contact" dialog.

Comment: I don't know if you're looking to create your own dialog or just have the built-in one pop up, but the 2nd answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895206/how-can-i-launch-the-add-contact-activity-in-android will take care of the latter. You just need to send the text from your textview as the second extra in the sample code.

Comment: @hBrent Could you make your comment an answer so I can mark it as my answer to help anyone else?

Comment: I made my comment an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the 2nd answer here: [How can I launch the 'Add Contact' activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895206/how-can-i-launch-the-add-contact-activity-in-android) will cause the built-in Android contacts dialog to open. You just need to send the text from your textview as the second extra in that sample code.