# How to open contacts and let user decide if he/she want to create or select one contact

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I'm trying to open contacts and let user decide if he/she want to **create** or **select** a contact to use it on my app.

I need something like this:
[image: I need something like this]

Where on the first option the user can add a new contact.

I tried the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
i.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true); // Fix for 4.0.3 +
startActivityForResult(i, CARREGA_CONTATOS);
```

But a got this error on Logcat (right after startActivityForResult):

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT_OR_EDIT typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact (has extras) }

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I tried this code also with similar result:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
);
startActivityForResult(intent, CARREGA_CONTATOS);
```

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT_OR_EDIT dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts }

**EDIT 2:**
Almost what I need:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
i.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true); // Fix for 4.0.3 +
startActivityForResult(i, CARREGA_CONTATOS);
```

But this code opens this image, and the user must select "Contacts" before it goes to where I want.
[image: But this code opens this image]

Comment: have you declared your activity in manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12722921/4029129

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html) seems to suggest using:

```
// Creates a new Intent to insert a contact
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Insert.ACTION);
// Sets the MIME type to match the Contacts Provider
intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

Comment: That code goes directly to **"New Contact"**. I need an option to let user select from an existing contact OR create a new one.

Comment: Have you tried it? The doc says it handles that for you.

Comment: Yes, i tried this... This [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html#EditContact) just edit an existing contact. I want to SELECT one or create a new. On my app I just need the name of that contact...

Comment: Then I think you'll have to do that yourself. Show a pop up where they do the selection, and based on that fire off one intent (retrieve the list and select) or the other (create new).

Comment: I'm avoiding this approach because the user might not know if the contact is already registered

Comment: Then you might be stuck having to build a complete UI yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to add the default category  `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)`
to make it match an an action.

Comment: I tried this code `Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
        );
        intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true); // Fix for 4.0.3 +
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CARREGA_CONTATOS);` but does not work