# Kivy start android intent with pre-filled contact fields

Tags: python, kivy, pyjnius

I want to start an android add contacts activity.But i also want to start the contact's intents insert action. What is wrong with my code here.

Simply i want to start a add contacts activity with pre filled data like phone and number already added.

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from jnius import cast
from jnius import autoclass
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')
Intents = autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract$Intents")
ContactsContract = autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract")
Contacts = autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract$Contacts")

class Main(FloatLayout):
    def go_site(self):
        # create the intent
        '''
        intent = Intent()
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/"))

        #############################################################

        intent = Intent()
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT)
        intent.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        '''


        intent =  Intent()
        intent.setAction(Intents.Insert.ACTION)
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE)
        #intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "")



        # PythonActivity.mActivity is the instance of the current Activity
        # BUT, startActivity is a method from the Activity class, not from our PythonActivity.
        # We need to cast our class into an activity and use it

        currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
        currentActivity.startActivity(intent)



class MainApp(App):

    def on_pause(self):
        # Here you can save data if needed
        return True

    def on_resume(self):

        # Here you can check if any data needs replacing (usually nothing)
        pass
    def build(self):
        return Main()         
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Answer found on Zarah's comment at the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895206/how-can-i-launch-the-add-contact-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Insert is an nested class. you need to use pyjnius nested class syntax.

this worked:

```
Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')
Intents = autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract$Intents")
Insert = autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract$Intents$Insert")
ContactsContract = autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract")
Contacts = autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract$Contacts")

class Main(FloatLayout):
    def go_site(self):
        intent = Intent()
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT)
        intent.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        intent.putExtra(Insert.NAME, "The Name")
        intent.putExtra(Insert.PHONE, "The Phone")
        intent.putExtra(Insert.COMPANY, "The Company")

        currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
        currentActivity.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: This works as it opens but the fields are still empty.