# Select contact for app

Tags: java, android, contacts

I ran into this post: [How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

Unfortunately I'm reading that it's old and Android 2.0 changed how this works, but this post fails to link to a new method of accomplishing this.  Google also appears to either lack results, or I'm not searching for the right thing.  I'd like for a user to be able to select a contact on my app... how do I give them a prompt to select 1 user, then for a task to be executed when that user is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `StartActivityForResult` on your contact picker Intent and then you will get the result back when the user selects the contact.  [Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker/) is a pretty good example

```
 Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
        Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
```

Comment: Here is a sample project that demonstrates this, and works for both the older and newer contacts APIs: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Pick

Comment: That tutorial shows `Bundle extras<string> = data.getExtras();`.... when I do `<string>` like that on Eclipse it says there's a problem... is that not the correct syntax?