# Get a contact phone number

Tags: android

When i open my contact list i want to able to select a person and get his(her) number. At the moment i can open the contact list, also, i have a onActivityResult witch is being fired when i select a person. The code is:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //get the selected person's phone number.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list).  You will need to call startActivityForResult, and then query the result for the phone number.

Comment: Thanks mate, as soon as i try the code, i will accept your answer.