# How to call in android?

Tags: android

How do I call international mobile programmatically when clicking textview in android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Android contacts list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

Answer (score 9):

you can call to any number using the following code:

```
String Numb = "tel:" + "your number";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(Numb));
startActivity(intent);
```

include following permission also:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```