# How to set my contacts application as the default?

Tags: android, default, contacts

Is it possible to replace Android's default contacts app? I want my custom app to load in place of the default contact application.

If this is possible, could you explain how this can be accomplished? If not, why? The default keyboard can be changed, why not an application?

Comment: u had done set default app.>?

Answer (score 1):

This is for the user to decide. Your application needs to be able to receive the Intent for picking an item from the contact list (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)). The user will decide then, if he wants to use your application as the default one.