# How to display native contacts inside my activity in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

I have created sample application which can call show all contacts (phone numbers). But the contacts are displayed in a new activity. But I want to create an activity with header view and footer view and the contacts to be displayed inside that view. How can I achieve this.

I have used the following code to fetch contacts

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
      intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good answer
[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)