# Open contact list to pick contact, or add a new one

Tags: android

In my application I need to pick a contact using the default contact application. I do that using:

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);`

But i'm missing the "Create New" button, which is there on the top. How can I get it?

Comment: tom, did you find the way to do this?

Comment: [How to call Android contacts list?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list

Comment: Have you read the question? It's not about how to open the contacts list, but it's how to get the "Create New" button on the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, this is not possible.
The only way is to create yourself the "ContactPickerActivity" so you can add what you want in it and for example your "Add a contact" button.

In your sample folder (samples/android-XX/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderCursor) you have a great exemple of how to achieve it.