# Ensure Android Compatibility Revisited

Tags: admob, android-compatibility

I have found already related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version/4994039#4994039) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291006/ensure-android-project-doesnt-call-apis-with-newer-than-intended-api-level)

*First of all lets note that I am an IntelliJ user*

So my question is if there are any updates on the matter on how to **keep compatibility without doing extra work**.

*As far as I have understood, the values inside the android manifest (min & target sdk) play a role only as a reference for google play and not for compiling*

I would like to support just the Gingerbread edition, **Android-10**.
On the other hand **AdMob** is forcing me to compile for **Android-13**.
Main issue is if in case by accident use a feature that there is in Android-13 but not in Android-10.

The only "solution" that I have come up so far is to **compile back and forth**. Change properties, compile, then change properties compile again. This is the least annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ADT from one version of Android (13) to generate your resources and the Android library from an earlier version (10) for compilation to ensure you haven't used any APIs from the later version.

I also use IntelliJ but build with Maven and this is what I do. Using Maven makes this use case quite simple.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
   <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <sdk>
          <platform>${android.resources.sdk.version}</platform>
      </sdk>
   </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <source>1.6</source>
       <target>1.6</target>
       <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
       <fork>true</fork>
   </configuration>
</plugin>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <version>${android.library.dependency.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try but since I am familiar with sbt I am not sure yet if your answer is the solution.