# android SDK differences

Tags: android, deprecated

My doubt is about the differences between different SDK's and how they affect our app development?
Let say i created an app with sdk api 22(lollipop) now can it be deployed to Android api 23(Marshmellow)?

And if possible what about the deprecated classes like Http from apache which is present in api 22 but deprecated in api 23?

Do i have to use different build tools to be able to deploy to different Versions?

And also what exactly does it mean to have a class deprecated?

I know this is a huge list of questions (more like whining) but these are a few doubts thats been nagging me for a while.

Thanking for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can deploy the app you developed with target api 22 to 23 by doing the following,

a. Change the target API to 23 or the latest and then recompile it again and build a new .APK

b. In case of changes like the one happened in M - they added run time permissions, we need to handle those, else there is no purpose you see.

2. Deprecated - [What does "This method is deprecated" mean for application developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449210/what-does-this-method-is-deprecated-mean-for-application-developers) this one gives you good insights on deprecated

No, you need not use different builds, you can find out the BUILD on run time and handle. More on that here - [How to deal with deprecated classes in Android to keep compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321649/how-to-deal-with-deprecated-classes-in-android-to-keep-compatibility)

All the best.

Comment: ok i kinda get the idea but what is run time permissions and so i can keep useing the deprecated apache packages? Http and volley which uses apache packages?

Comment: run time permissions are newly added in M - that is earlier users would be asked to give permission like camera, storage write/read etc during installation, but now users will be asked during run time. that is camera permission will be requested only when user uses the camera in our app. more on this http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html and yes about while deprecated package can be used, it is better to move to latest at the earliest in case if we want support on issues and also address any new facility the class provides.

Comment: please do accept the answer in case if addresses your queries. let me know if you need any information in addition to the one shared already. Thank you and all the best.