# Do I have to use Deprecated methods along with the new ones?

Tags: java, android, api, deprecated, locationmanager

So i'm making an application, and i'm using Maps API on Android and i have these two methods

```
locManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(Callback){}
locManager.addGpsStatusListener(Listener){}
@Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int i) {
    Log.i("gps status mudou",111+"");
}
```

So, the first one was implemented in API level 24 and the other one deprecated, since i want this application to work in almost all devices, what i want to know is if i have to use both methods or just one of them, and if is just one what should i use? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with deprecated classes in Android to keep compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321649/how-to-deal-with-deprecated-classes-in-android-to-keep-compatibility)