# Android: Create BroadcastReceiver that starts when User pick Contact

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contacts

I'm programming app that need to make a check on a contact, when user select him from his contact list. the check should start only when the selection event take place.

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such broadcast. Selection event is not something that is normally broadcasted by Android.

You need to call Contact Peeker from your app in order to implement custom check on selection result. For this see [How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list).

Comment: and how about tracking outgoing call to contact? and put her on hold for 2 seconds, and after it continue or cancel the call?