# how to get the total number of contact in our contactlist android

Tags: android

friends ....how to get  total length of our contact in contact list save in mobile .means how to fetch total no of contacts saved in our mobile ...android....

```
public class justexmple extends Activity {
    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
    private Button startBtn;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link, a similar question posted on Stackoverflow.

[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

or check this link, in this we have complete source code which answers your question. and also source code is there for download as a zip file.

http://sonyarouje.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/list-contactsmy-first-android-app/

Hope these links fetch you the required answer.