# Android - How to call contact screen through our application

Tags: android

How to push contact app through our application and return back to our application with new modify details.
It is possible or not?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2008/12/display-contact-names-in-android.html check this

Answer (score 0):

From here: [How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

I'm not 100% sure what your question is supposed to ask, but the following snippet should help you 'call the contacts list function, pick a contact, then return to [your] app with the contact's name'.

There are three steps to this process.

**1) Permissions**

Add a permission to read contacts data to your application manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

**2) Calling the Contact Picker**

Within your Activity, create an Intent that asks the system to find an Activity that can perform a PICK action from the items in the Contacts URI.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);
```

Call `startActivityForResult`, passing in this Intent (and a request code integer, `PICK_CONTACT` in this example). This will cause Android to launch an Activity that's registered to support `ACTION_PICK` on the `People.CONTENT_URI`, then return to this Activity when the selection is made (or canceled).

```
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

**3) Listening for the Result**

Also in your Activity, override the `onActivityResult` method to listen for the return from the 'select a contact' Activity you launched in step 2. You should check that the returned request code matches the value you're expecting, and that the result code is `RESULT_OK`.

You can get the URI of the selected contact by calling `getData()` on the *data* Intent parameter. To get the name of the selected contact you need to use that URI to create a new query and extract the name from the returned cursor.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

  switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT) :
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
          String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
          // TODO Whatever you want to do with the selected contact name.
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, you will need to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Next, within your activity, you would use something like:

```
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id =  cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            }
    }
```

This queries for contacts and gets id and name.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to send an `ACTION_EDIT` intent to Contacts

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(iduri);
i.setData(uri);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
i.setData(Uri.parse(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI + "/" + id));
startActivityForResult(i, some_int_EDIT_CONTACT);
```

or better

```
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, read_id);
i.setData(contactUri);
startActivityForResult(i, some_int_EDIT_CONTACT);
```

assuming you have the contact id