# Onclick Listener for TableRow to open phone Contacts?

Tags: android

I have written an application with 5 Table Rows. What I want to do is, when i click on a particular Table Row, i want the Phone Contacts to be opened, and the selected contact be displayed on that Table Row. For Example : If I press table row 5, Contacts is opened and the selected contact should be placed on the Table row 5.
I hope I am clear enough.
Can you Please help me with this?

Comment: At which of the point you name are you getting. stuck?

Comment: Actually I am having problems in opening the phone contacts when clicked on the Table row and I want to know how to display the selected number on the particular row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another question about this has been answered:
[How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list)

For placing the contact into the right row, save a reference to the row from the onClickListener so this listrow can be altered when a contact has been selected. You could add a new child (addView) or replace some text that is one of the columns..

```
// Assumes you have some reference to the tablerow in the onClickListener.. like:
public void onClick(View v) { 
    if (v instanceof TableRow) {
         TableRow tr = (TableRow) v;

         String contactName = yourFunctionToGetAContact();

         TextView newContactTextView = new TextView(this); // replace this by your reference to your context (e.g. activity)
         newContactTextView.setText(contactName);
         tr.addView(newContactTextView, 0); // 0 means insert at first column
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help..the contacts part worked..but is it possible for u to send me some code regarding placing the contact in the row??

Comment: Did this answer your question? If not, please explain what is unclear. If it did answer your question, could you please mark the answer as the answer?