# Initializing a Loader in an Activity

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

I am currently trying to learn how to use Loaders and am having trouble starting a Loader in my activity.

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

public class ASwitchActivity extends Activity implements 
             LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<SampleLoader.SampleLoaderResult> {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    public Loader<SampleLoader.SampleLoaderResult> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
      return new SampleLoader(getBaseContext(), account, "dog");
}

  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<SampleLoader.SampleLoaderResult> loader, SampleLoader.SampleLoaderResult out)
  {
      TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.testTV);
      t.setText("yay");
  }

  public void onLoaderReset(Loader<SampleLoader.SampleLoaderResult> loader){

  }
}
```

However Eclipse gives an error stating:

> The method initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks)
>   in the type LoaderManager is not applicable for the arguments (int,
>   null, ActivitySwitchActivity)

Can anyone help with where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As I can see you use supportV4 library.
So to implement Loader you should do some things:

1. extend your activity from FragmentActivity class
2. Use getSupportLoaderManager method instead of getLoaderManager

here is sample code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object> {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<Object> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle){
    return null; // TODO
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Object o) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onLoadFinished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader)    {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onLoaderReset", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: What if you originally extended `ListActivity`?  There is no such thing as a `FragmentListActivity` that I can drop in as a replacement.

Comment: @MattHuggins ListActivity is mainly a convenience for very few things - you can implement the missing functionality yourself (keep ListView as field)

Answer (score 11):

When using loaders with `fragments` use:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
```

And when using loaders with `Activity` use:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
```

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter for `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` should be a instance that implement interface `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`
So you should implement the interface first.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post my complete code earlier, only an excerpt. What do you mean by the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks interface? Would they be the onCreateLoader, onLoadFinished, and onLoaderReset? because I have them in my program?

Answer (score 1):

For AppCompatActivity use `getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);` for initializing the loader.