# getLoadManager().initLoader(0, null, this) does not acceptable

Tags: android, listview

1. API level is 8
2. I am sure that I use the support package
3. i get the getLoadManager().initLoader(0, null, this) does not acceptable

my code is as below:

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
 public class ListViewLoader extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{

// This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

// These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve
static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.Data._ID, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME };

// This is the select criteria
static final String SELECTION = "((" + ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND (" + ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a progress bar to display while the list loads
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    getListView().setEmptyView(progressBar);

    // Must add the progress bar to the root of the layout
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    root.addView(progressBar);

    // For the cursor adapter, specify which columns go into which views
    String[] fromColumns = { ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME };
    int[] toViews = { android.R.id.text1 }; // The TextView in simple_list_item_1

    // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
    // We pass null for the cursor, then update it in onLoadFinished()
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, fromColumns, toViews);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Prepare the loader. Either re-connect with an existing one,
    // or start a new one.
    getLoadManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

// Called when a new Loader needs to be created
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
{
    // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
    // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
    return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);
}

// Called when a previously created loader has finished loading
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
{
    // Swap the new cursor in. (The framework will take care of closing the
    // old cursor once we return.)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

// Called when a previously created loader is reset, making the data unavailable
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
{
    // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
    // above is about to be closed. We need to make sure we are no
    // longer using it.
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    // Do something when a list item is clicked
}
```

}

Comment: What is the exact error, stacktrace?

Comment: you should check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918397/initializing-a-loader-in-an-activity). to get loader manager through support library you need to do couple of things which are outlined in the post