# Android - How to create a control to pick a contact from my phones contact?

Tags: android

I want to create a control on a user form so that whenever i click on it, my phones contact list is shown with Search , indexing and grouping functionality same as android contact application and i would pick any contact and return to my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna have a look at this: [How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list?answertab=active#tab-top)

There are three steps basically.

1. Add Read Contacts Permission in your Manifest
2. Call the Contact Picker with the right intent and `startActivityForResult(..)`
3. Listen for the result from the Contacts Intent. And process it any way you want.

Comment: It works fine when i use this in activtiy class but in my case i want to use this functionality in one of my fragment. In my fragment class. I am getting only a single error on managedQuery method;

Comment: getActivity().getContentResolver().query() instead of managedQuery.

Answer (score 0):

User Android contact ContentProvider to access phone contact number and other information.

Thanks