# making a contact list

Tags: android, contacts

I'm teaching myself android programming. I'm looking for a good contact list tutorial (it'll help me with content providers and the sqlite database).  I've spent hours on google looking for one but they are mostly outdated and the few that I found that aren't give code examples but no explanations.  I've looked on the google developers site but that honestly confuses me more than helps me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**: You must have read the [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) on the Andoid developer site regarding retrieving a list of contacts. It shows the steps you might need to take. There is also a sample of the code in the `API Demos` which you can find in `android-sdk/samples/android-X/ApiDemo/` in your system( if you've installed samples). If you haven't installed samples you can install that from `android sdk manager` for your version of sdk.

**2**: There is one good answer of [How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list) question. Following the steps would help you.

Hope after reading the two links and trying to understand the sample code in API Demos you would be able to deal with it better. All the best!

Comment: THANK YOU!!  That google link is perfect.  I don't know why I couldn't find that one, I found this one: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html    and it reads like stereo instructions to me.  Also, what you put for #2, I saw that earlier, but a commenter said that code was depreciated so I didn't linger

Comment: okay. generally, I first go through the API demos for anything that I want to learn. This way I have a tested demo code for the android-sdk version that I use. So, you might want to try the API demos as well.

Comment: I have very little experience with the API demos.  I'm still slowly working my way into them.  Thanks again for the help