# How to read whatsapp contact list

Tags: android, contacts, whatsapp

I'm trying to make a text-view which on click shows the contact or when we type any letter its shows suggestions of contact.
I'm able to read contact from contact book,now i want a text-view which shows only WHATS-APP contact to select.
please help me out to read WHATS APP contacts.

Comment: you can use shared prefrence.

Comment: shared preference can be used to retrieve the data,here my point is to open WHATS APP contact list.
Its nothing to relate with shared preference

Comment: @eduardohl no that is not duplicate. They didn't ask for api.

Comment: Nice question , but at the end whats app have no any api so you can't do this

Comment: pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list?rq=1

Comment: is there any way to open whats app contact list..?

Comment: @Yushi try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448250/how-to-get-only-whatsapp-contact-from-android for retrieve all whatsapp account contacts..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at 100% sure, but I think WhatsApp does not have a API or so you could use and because WhatsApp also only reads the contact list and compare this with their database, it seems that there is no way. 
I know that there were API's, but they weren't made by WhatsApp themself and were deleted for "WhatsApp Inc.'s copyrights and trademarks".
I read that this was a libary or API or something like this for WhatsApp: https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup
But it's also deleted for DMCA issues.

Comment: hi fmaster, thanks for your reply
is there any alternative way to open whats app contact list,if no api support is there.