# Android contact list picker

Tags: java, android, contacts, addressbook

I have 2 activities:

the first - is just an opening page and it has a button that goes to the second activity

the second activity - will open up the contact list and will allow the user to pick contacts and retrieve their numbers - they will be saved for later use.

My problem is I can not figure out how to get it to work in the second activity. All the examples only have the contact list in the Main/first activity and I am really new to this and don't understand how to get it to move to the second.

my code I have right now

Main.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Contacts.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});

}
}
```

Main XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"     tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Contacts java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class Contacts extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
}


}
```

Contacts XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="akh.seniorproj.Contacts">



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution: [How to call Android contacts list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list?answertab=active#tab-top)
Its pretty much what you need to do but instead name you should search the number with the cursor.

Comment: Great! Set the question as answered please.